# Pagination: How can I keep the user selected on the first page?

Tags: php, laravel

When moving to the second page, the user selected on the first page is unchecked.
And Only the user selected on the second page is stored.
How can I keep the user selected on the first page?
I'm using Laravel10.

This is my code

## Blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', 'All Casts')

@section('content')
<form action="{{ route('movie.storeCasts', $movie->id) }}" method="post">
    @csrf
    @method('PATCH')

    <div class="row row-cols-4 g-4 mb-5">
        @forelse ($all_casts as $cast)
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card h-100">
                    <img src="{{ $cast->avatar }}" class="card-img-top" alt="{{ $cast->name }}" style="height: 200px; object-fit:cover;">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">{{ $cast->name }}</h5>
                        <p class="card-text text-secondary">From <strong>{{ $cast->country }}</strong></p>
                        
                        <div class="mb-3 d-flex">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="cast[]" id="selected_casts_{{ $cast->id }}" class="form-check me-2" value="{{ $cast->id }}"
                                    {{ $movie->movieCast->contains('cast_id', $cast->id) ? 'checked' : '' }}>
                            <label for="selected_casts_{{ $cast->id }}" class="form-input">Checked</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        @empty
            <p class="text-center lead text-white">No Casts yet.</p>
        @endforelse
    </div>
</form>

<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    {{ $all_casts->links() }}
</div>
@endsection
```

## Controller

```
    public function storeCasts(Request $request, $movie_id) {
    $movie = $this->movie->findOrFail($movie_id);

    $movie->movieCast()->delete();

    if($request->cast) {
        $selected_casts = [];
        foreach($request->cast as $cast_id) {
            $selected_casts[] = ['cast_id' => $cast_id];
        }
        $movie->movieCast()->createMany($selected_casts);
    }
    
    return redirect()->route('movie.edit', $movie_id);
}
```

Comment: you are clicking a hyperlink not submitting a form

Answer (score 0):

To keep track of the selected casts across pagination, you can use session storage or query parameters to store and retrieve the selected cast IDs. Here's how you can implement it using session storage

When a user selects a cast, store the selected cast IDs in the session.
When rendering the casts, check if a cast ID exists in the session storage. If it does, mark the checkbox as checked

```
    public function index()
    {
        $all_casts = Cast::paginate(10);
        $selected_casts = session()->get('selected_casts', []);    
        return view('casts.index', compact('all_casts', 'selected_casts'));
    }


    public function storeCasts(Request $request, $movie_id)
    {
     session()->put('selected_casts', $request->cast);
    
        return redirect()->route('movie.edit', $movie_id);
    }
```

change In your blade template

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cast[]" id="selected_casts_{{ $cast->id }}" class="form-check me-2" value="{{ $cast->id }}"
    {{ in_array($cast->id, $selected_casts) ? 'checked' : '' }}>
<label for="selected_casts_{{ $cast->id }}" class="form-input"> Checked</label>
```